# Reducing HTML File Size - something more than minimisation?

Tags: html, compression, size

I've been looking in `Firebug` at the `Net` tab where it shows the size of files.

A lot of high traffic sites seemingly have surprisingly small initial GET sizes for the url.

For example, `GET www.hostmonster.com` comes in at 3.9KB. (Apologies to those who are offended by the example.)

If I put the hostmonster HTML source into an editor, though, it saves at 12KB. If I run it through an online compressor, it only reduces it to 11KB.

What is going on that it's down to 3.9KB?

Comment: Have you examined the contents of the 3.9KB? Look at it in a browser and see if it's different. Maybe the wget useragent means you're being given a different result.

Comment: i have used the php Gzip compression it reduced the size 12 to 3 you can try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Gzipping. Check out [the most recent CSS Tricks screencast](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/114-lets-do-simple-stuff-to-make-our-websites-faster/) it will take you through many techniques to speed up your site and will describe how to setup Gzipping much better than I can here.

Comment: Thanks for the screencast link. Some I knew; other bits were new :)

Answer (score 1):

GZip or Deflate compression.

Most often through the Content-Encoding header (though we're really all using it as a transfer encoding, but support for that is poor).

Answer (score 1):

you can use the either GZip or Deflate comparison for that you need to get the module on in Apache for Deflate its the `deflate_module` and for Gzip its the `mod_gzip`

i would recommended the mod Gzip

to learn [How to install mod_gzip](http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/install.htm)

and the live example of the mod_gzip is below

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's compressed, you can see the real size below the transferred amount:

[image]